# How to add remarks to existing column using liquibase

Tags: java, liquibase

I'm working in posgresql database, and I want to overwrite an existing comment in a column of a table using liquibase, so I have : 
 `mytable (column1 int) --This is a comment`

I know that I can do it in a SQL native way, like this:

```
<changeSet author="myuser" id="123456">
        <sql dbms="postgresql">
            COMMENT ON COLUMN mytable.column1 IS 'This is my new comment';
        </sql>
</changeSet>
```

Is there any way to make this change without relying on a native mechanism?

Answer (score 6):

There is a special Change Type [setColumnRemarks](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/set-column-remarks.html) to add a remark on existing column:

```
<changeSet author="myuser" id="123456">
    <setColumnRemarks
        columnName="column1"
        remarks="This is my new comment"
        tableName="mytable"/>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [renameColumn](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/rename-column.html) Type to liquibase providing the newColumnName the same as the oldColumnName - even thought I am not sure if it will work with PostgreSQL:

```
<changeSet  author="myuser"  id="123456">  
    <renameColumn
            newColumnName="column1"  
            oldColumnName="column1"  
            remarks="This is my new comment" 
            tableName="mytable"/>  
</changeSet>
```

Comment: this didn't work for any db. tried with postgres, oracle and msssql